# Rascal: Can a Function return a Function

Tags: higher-order-functions, rascal

The Rascal documentation has an [example of a function](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Concepts/Functions/Functions.html) that takes a function as an argument:

```
int f(int x, int (int) multi){ return multi(x); }
```

Conversely, what is the syntax for a function that returns a function?

I couldn't find an example and tried things along the line:

```
(int (int)) f() {return (int y) {return y;}}
```

but got syntax errors in the repl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
int two(int n) = 2 * n;
int(int) g() = two;
```

Function `two` multiplies by 2 and `g` returns the function `two`.
Observe that the return type of `g` is `int(int)`, a type describing a function which returns an `int` and has one `int` argument.

A similar effect can be achieved by an inline definition:

```
int(int) g() = int(int n) { return 2 * n; };
```

You can also use this same notation inside other functions. For instance, you could create a function which multiplies two numbers:

```
int mult(int n, int m) = n * m;
```

If you use it, you would get what you would expect:

```
rascal>mult(3,4);
int: 12
```

You can instead return a function that essentially partially applies this function as follows:

```
int(int) multBy(int n) { 
    return int(int m) { 
        return mult(n,m); 
    }; 
}
int (int) (int)
```

So, this returns a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int (int)`, i.e., a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`. You can then use it as so:

```
rascal>multBy3 = multBy(3);
int (int)

rascal>multBy3(4);
int: 12
```

You can find more examples in some of our (many) files with tests:

- `lang::rascal::tests::basic::Functions`
- `lang::rascal::tests::functionality::FunctionComposition`

Thanks for your question, we have more documentation to do!

Comment: Ok, so that means returning a function result is only possible in the equational variant of function definitions, right?!

Comment: No, you could also return a function from inside another function. I'll extend the example to show how.

Comment: Ah, right, now I see what has to be changed in my approach. This `int(int) f() {return int(int y){return y;};}` compiles. So "curly" definitions can also return a function .

Comment: Thanks to @MarkHills for the very useful extension of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to my failed attempt is:

- leave out the outermost parens in the return type of `f`
- add the return type `int` of the anonymous function that is returned by `f`
- don't forget the semi after `f`'s `return` statement

That gives:

```
int (int) f() { return int (int y) { return y; } ; }
```